# Reading wrong value from dataset

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dataset

I have a question related with dataset. I wonder why am I reading wrong value from a dataset?

The field that I want to read has the value of:  2010-06-28 21:00:00

However, when I'm trying to read the first row using:

DateTime endShift = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["rep_time_to"]);

I get: 04/07/2010 9:00:00 PM

As you can see this value is correct except the date.

Why should I do to get the correct value which is 2010-06-28 21:00:00?

Thanks in advance.

A newbie programmer!

Comment: What's `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["rep_time_to"]` before calling *convert*? Maybe try to change the time in the DB to e.g. 21:38:17 and see what your program reads. Is it the right cell?

Comment: Works for me.. Have you tried just hardcoding it like DateTime endShift = Convert.ToDateTime("2010-06-28 21:00:00") ?

Comment: Have you inspected the dataset returned to confirm that '2010-06-28 21:00:00' is actually what is stored?

Answer (score 0):

Some questions:

1. What's your current culturecode
2. Why are you storing a date not as a datetime or equivalent?
3. What is the actual field type?

Some hints: 
1. Convert the db value to a string if it isn't already.
2. Try DateTime.Parse
3. Change your DB field to datetime or equivalent, to avoid conversion.